# onClick and onTouch on TextView?

Tags: android

I want to do something when the user touch (or click) on a TextView but I can't seems to make it work.

I simply place a TextView in Layout and I tryied to set an onclick listener.

```
        touchTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.touchTV);
    touchTV.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {

            public void onClick(View v)
                {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Text Touch",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                }
        });
```

But nothing happen when I click on the TextView.

I tryied the same thing but with an onTouch listener but I get the same (lack of) result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You forgot to call show() on the Toast and so it was never displayed; its a common mistake :-)
Change code to:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Text Touch",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: You are polite. You could have said: it's a stupid mistake ;o)  Thanks