# selecting one word in a TextView in android

Tags: android, select, textview

I want copy to clipboard one word from my TextView by double click or long click (or in some another way). Is it posible?

Thank you for your time in advance!!!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092564/onclick-and-ontouch-on-textview

Comment: On Android this is usually done with a Menu button option called "select text."

Comment: I know how to selecte all text from my TextView, but I need selecte only one word. Searching in google or here didn't bring any results for solve my problem. I want to know is it possible in general? Thank you

Comment: What about selecting the whole text and then just parse the word out?

Comment: Yes, parsing is a good idea, I thinked about it but I have no imagenation how to find needed word in whole text...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an EditText, and set the attribute editable to false. Like this:

```
<EditTextandroid:id="@+id/edittext"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:editable="false"/>
```

Then get the edittext in your java code:

```
EditText edit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext);
```

Then put the following into a listener - a LongPressListener for instance.

```
OnLongClickListener lc = new OnClickListener(){

     @Override
     public boolean onLongClick(View view){

    int selection_start = edit.getSelectionStart();
    int selection_end = edit.getSelectionEnd();

    String copy = edit.getText().toString().subString(selection_start, selection_end);

    ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE); 

    clipboard.setText(copy);
    return false;
    }
 };

 edit.setOnLongClickListener(lc);
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried your code and it works fine. It's a good idea and I'll work in this direction.

Answer (score 0):

Use any listner of your choice on the text view but remember to make it focusable in touch mode in the xml for the text view in question.

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:clickable="true"
```

After this is done use the following code to copy the text after casting the view object to a text view.

```
void onClick(View v)
{
    TextView tv = (TextView) v;
    ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
    clipboard.setText(tv.getText());
}
```